# Why is my Access Form Changing my Fields when I save it?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-forms

I'm relatively new to Access and I'm working on putting together a database for a sports league. I have 2 tables that are set out like the following:

Table 1 - Teams:

- Team_ID (autonumber, Primary Key)
- Name (Short Text)

Table 2 - Results:

- Game_ID (autonumber, Primary Key)
- Home_Team_ID (Foreign Key from Table 1)
- Away_Team_ID (Foreign Key from Table 1)
- Winning_Team_ID (Foreign Key from Table 1)

I've made a form that displays the Home/Away/Winning_Team_ID's from Table 2 however I'm really struggling to display the Team Names (from the link to the Table 1).

In the Record Source for the form, I've linked Table 2 to three copies of Table 1, and then linked the Primary key's from the three Table 1's to the Foreign key's (Home/Away/Winning_Team_ID's) to Table 2 as seen below.

[image: Record Source]

This gives me the exact data I need when I go to View the results from this query.

The issue is, when I try to "Add Existing Fields" into the Design View of the form and then save it, all 3 (Home, Away and Winning) show the same value (The Home Value).

Before I save - Exactly what I need:
[image: Before Save]

After I save - Field on the right has changed:
[image: After Save]

(Note: The difference between the 2 above images is the change from `"Teams_1.Name"` on the right, to `"Teams.Name"`)

I have no idea why, when I save it, it changes to the above automatically. If I add the fields and don't save and just go to layout view, it works perfectly, but as soon as I save it it changes all of the fields to the same one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this issue arises is because the three fields have identical field names in the SQL code constituting the Record Source for the form (albeit the table qualifiers differ), and so when MS Access validates the Control Source of each control on the form, it disregards the table qualifier and assigns the first field with matching field name in the Record Source.

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1. Assign an alias to the two other `Name` fields in the Record Source for the form, e.g.:

   ```sql
   select 
       Teams.Name as Home_Team, 
       Teams_1.Name as Away_Team, 
       Teams_2.Name as Winning_Team 
   from 
       (
           (
               Results left join Teams on
               Results.Home_Team_ID = Teams.Team_ID
           )
           left join Teams as Teams_1 on 
           Results.Away_Team_ID = Teams_1.Team_ID
       )
       left join Teams as Teams_2 on
       Results.Winning_Team_ID = Teams_2.Team_ID
   ```
2. Create a saved query containing the data that you wish to display on the form, and then specify the saved query as the Record Source for the form - using this method avoids the need to assign aliases to the fields.

Personally, I would suggest using the first method described above, as the Control Sources for the controls on your form will be more descriptive and easier to maintain going forward.